# Must all media go in 'static' folder?

Tags: flask

I'm trying out Flask as a simple alternative to Django.

Immediately I see that images are probably served ONLY from the static folder.

Is this true? What if I wish have a folder classification of 'photos', is it possible to do so?

Or must we always use "static"?

Comment: there can be arbitrary number of sub-directories under the static folder. e.g. `url_for('static', filename='img/photos/outdoors/1.jpg')` does this help?

Comment: thank you - that might have been confusion on my part then